# copy all non-conflict files between branches

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm working on a branch `b`and I had some files changed on master after making the branch from other users, I want to copy all non-conflict files from `master` to my branch `b`. I don't want to do merge as I'm still working on the branch.

Thanx,

Comment: Have you tried rebasing `b` onto `master`?

Comment: No, can you explain what are the results after doing rebase?

Comment: What will happen with the files that have conflict between branches?

Comment: Rebasing will apply your extra commits on branch `b` in order you committed them on top of the `master` branch - the result is as if you committed all those changes again. If there are conflicts, you will have to resolve them. If you have changed file `X` in 5 of your commits, and this file has changed drastically on `master`, you will have to resolve conflicts in file `X` for each of your 5 commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git rebase master` when you are on your `<branch>`. What it will do basically, take your `branch` and bring ito the top index of `master` branch.

It looks something like this

[image: rebase]

**Reference**

[Git Rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to merge because you don't want to create a half-done commit, you could always stash your changes ('git stash'), merge with master, and then reapply your changes on top of master ('git stash pop'). The result is your working directory will be your branch + master + your uncommitted changes.